# Как можно использовать Sass и Pug вместе с React (Create-React-App)?

Tags: reactjs, sass, scss, pug, create-react-app

Обычно пишу html на pug, css - на scss. С Реактом из-за этого возникли проблемы, т.к. на вёрстку и стилизацию уходит много времени. Хочу как обычно писать на pug и scss. Возможно ли их троих подружить как-нибудь?